# How to use Node.js packages within a client-side html document using browserify

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, browserify

I'm unable to use a node.js module on my website with broweserify. The example only shows how to run a javascript file that is separate from the .html file, not how to use the node.js module *within* the .html file. Seems like a trivial problem, but I'm unable to make it work.

Here's what I've done:

1. Initialized node.js & installed a package, `npm i webtorrent-health` as an example
2. Created `require_stuff.js` which consists of a single line: `var WebtorrentHealth = require('webtorrent-health')`
3. Run browserify: `browserify require_stuff.js > bundle.js`
4. Include package in my html document, e.g. `<script src='bundle.js'></script>`
5. Use the package somewhere in my document, e.g. like this: `<script>webtorrentHealth(magnet).then(foobazbar())</script>`

Despite `bundle.js` executing and seemingly defining webtorrentHealth, the script within the .html document fails with `WebtorrentHealth is not defined`. What am I doing wrong? How do I make it work? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You're very close to what you want to achieve. In fact, your code bundle.js is inaccessible from outside (in your case the browser) due to browserify, but you can expose your module by writing at the end of your file require_stuff.js:

window.WebtorrentHealth = WebtorrentHealth;

Now you can use WebtorrentHealth in your document.